# How to open symlink

Tags: perl, logging, apache2

I need to reprogram some PHP and shell scripts of ISPConfig CP to use it with some other technologies.

For log rotation it uses a script named `vlogger`. I got it running, but one function for opening log files gives me errors.

> No such file or directory can't open /var/www/website_name/log/20170623-access.log at /usr/local/ispconfig/server/scripts/vlogger line 447,  line 2.

The weird thing is that it writes into the files but gives the error that's in the `or die()`.

```
open $vhost, ">>${vhost}" . time2str( $TEMPLATE, time() )
  or die ( "can't open $LOGDIR/${vhost}" . time2str( $TEMPLATE, time() ) );
```

The `$vhost` variable is normally `website_name/log/`. Before the changes `website_name` was a directory, but now it's a symlink that links to `client/website1/` where the `log` directory is.

How to rewrite this function so it will ignore that the `$vhost` is a symlink, or what else could be causing the problem?

Comment: You should add `$!` to the error message. That's the error the system returned. It will help spot the problem.

Comment: Or check https://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html which dies on `open` in informative manner.

Comment: adding $! gives me just the same error. "No such file or directory can't open /var/www/website_name/log/20170623-access.log at /usr/local/ispconfig/server/scripts/vlogger line 447, <STDIN> line 2."

Comment: What is the output of `perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper[-d, -w] for pop' /var/www/website_name/log/` I da, `${vhost}` nije isto kao i `$LOGDIR/${vhost}`

Answer (score 3):

You're overwriting `$vhost` with the file handle from the `open` call. That means your `open` will work once, and you can write to `$vhost`, but the next time you try to open the log file `$vhost` no longer contains a directory path and the `open` will fail

You should also use the three-parameter form of `open`, like this

```
my $log_file = $vhost . time2str( $TEMPLATE, time() );

open my $log_fh, '>>', $log_file
    or die qq{Unable to open "$log_file" for appending: $!};

print $log_fh ...;
```

Comment: This floods the log with a new error "Global symbol "$log_file" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $log_file"?) at /usr/local/ispconfig/server/scripts/vlogger line 454". Oh I never programed in perl or know its syntax.

Comment: @Sam_slo Okay I apologise. That was a problem that I spotted when I posted the code and thought I had fixed. I've corrected it now.

Comment: could see that myself. :) Your code would probbably work, but I can't use it because other code in the whole function needs $vhost to work. With your code I get an error in the next command that it can't find the file because only "website_name/log/" is in $vhost and not the path with the file name that is created with the $TEMPLATE. Thanks anyway!